# Bridging the qualitative and quantitative aspects of UX design

Tags: discussion, tags

It occurred to me that there are not many tags devoted to the description of more qualitative aspects of UX, such as clarity, accuracy, precision, simplicity, etc. I was wondering whether it is a good way to try and bridge the gap between the qualitative and quantitative aspects of UX if we start trying to incorporate tags in the questions that relate an aspect of UX design to what the feelings that the user would get.

For example, many questions ask for the simplest or most efficient way to do something, and the tags would relate to the actual item or object, but not necessarily the end outcome or design objective unless it was a standard UX metric (e.g. readability, usability). Is this a possibility to explore in UXSE?